# Running correlations in SparkR: no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Tags: r, apache-spark, r-s4, sparkr

I've recently started using SparkR and would like to run some
correlation analysis with it. I'm able to upload content in as a
SparkR dataframe but it doesn't permit to run simple cor() analysis
with the data frame. (Getting an S4 error below):

```
usr/local/src/spark/spark-1.5.1/bin/sparkR --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3
```

```r
library(SparkR)

setwd('/DATA/')

Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0" "sparkr-shell"')

sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

df <- read.df(sqlContext, "/DATA/GSE45291/GSE45291.csv", source = "com.databricks.spark.csv", inferSchema = "true")

results <- cor(as.data.matrix(df), type="pearson")
```

> data.matrix(df)Error in as.vector(data) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Is there no built-in correlation function for SparkR? How can I fix the S4 object to work in R where I can perform base functions? Any
suggestions folks have is appreciated.
Thanks
-Rich

Comment: If you can post the output of `str(df)` there might be hope of understanding what portions of that object might be suitable for coercion to a matrix.

Comment: @42- Short answer is none. Spark data frame is mostly a thin wrapper around Java object which contains only a recipe how to create / transform dataset not a data itself. Unless data is collected there is nothing to use here.

Comment: > str(df)
Formal class 'DataFrame' [package "SparkR"] with 2 slots
  ..@ env:<environment: 0x2d0a620> 
  ..@ sdf:Class 'jobj' <environment: 0x2d960c8>

Answer (score 2):

**Spark < 1.6**

> How can I fix the S4 object to work in R where I can perform base functions?

You simply cannot. Spark data frames are not a drop in replacement for standard R `data.frame`. If you want, you can collect to local R `data.frame`, but most of the time it won't be a feasible solution.

You can use an UDF to compute correlation between individual columns. First you'll need a Hive context:

```
sqlContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc)
```

and some dummy data:

```
ldf <- iris[, -5]
colnames(ldf) <- tolower(gsub("\\.", "_", colnames(ldf)))
sdf <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, ldf)
```

Next you have to register temporary table:

```
registerTempTable(sdf, "sdf")
```

Now you can use SQL query like this:

```
q <- sql(sqlContext, "SELECT corr(sepal_length, sepal_width) FROM sdf")
head(q)
##          _c0
## 1 -0.1175698
```

**Spark >= 1.6**

You can use `cor` function on a `DataFrame` directly.

Comment: So if I had a csv with a large numerical matrix and would like to run a pearson correlation on it (for example cor(as.data.matrix(df), type="pearson"), what approach would you suggest in spark? Is there a way to approach this with sparkR? Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't use R or specifically SparkR. Spark MLlib distributed matrices provide functionality you need in Scala but it has no R API. Alternatively R has some nice libraries like `bigmemory`. Finally you can just naively build a query string with `expand.grid` and `paste`.